# Salt GITFS Formulas Not Being Downloaded

Tags: python, git, amazon-web-services, configuration, salt-stack

I followed this [tutorial](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/conventions/formulas.html) to try to install the apache-formual from github.  I updated the `/etc/salt/master` file, restarted the daemon in the foreground with `-l debug` and here is my `top.sls` and `test.sls`

```
/etc/salt/master
gitfs_remotes:
   - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/jenkins-formula.git
   - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/apache-formula.git

top.sls
base:
    ip-172-31-56-169.ec2.internal:
        - test
test.sls
include:
    - apache
```

I then try to run the minion and receive the following error

```
ip-172-31-56-169.ec2.internal:
Data failed to compile:
----------
Specified SLS apache in saltenv base is not available on the salt master or through a configured fileserver.
```

The output of the salt daemon is:

```
[INFO    ] Clear payload received with command publish
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded local_cache.prep_jid
[DEBUG   ] Sending event - data = {'_stamp': '2015-08-  19T21:22:53.239357', 'minions': ['ip-172-31-56-169.ec2.internal']}
[DEBUG   ] Sending event - data = {'tgt_type': 'glob', 'jid': '20150819212253239143', 'tgt': '*', '_stamp': '2015-08-19T21:22:53.240005', 'user': 'sudo_ubuntu', 'arg': [], 'fun': 'state.highstate', 'minions': ['ip-172-31-56-169.ec2.internal']}
[INFO    ] User sudo_ubuntu Published command state.highstate with jid 20150819212253239143
[DEBUG   ] Published command details {'tgt_type': 'glob', 'jid': '20150819212253239143', 'tgt': '*', 'ret': '', 'user': 'sudo_ubuntu', 'arg':   [], 'fun': 'state.highstate'}
[INFO    ] Clear payload received with command _auth
[INFO    ] Authentication request from ip-172-31-56-169.ec2.internal
[INFO    ] Authentication accepted from ip-172-31-56-169.ec2.internal
[DEBUG   ] Sending event - data = {'id': 'ip-172-31-56-169.ec2.internal', '_stamp': '2015-08-19T21:22:53.256533', 'result': True, 'pub': '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMII..-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n', 'act': 'accept'}
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded roots.envs
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded roots.envs
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded jinja.render
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded yaml.render
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded roots.envs
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded roots.envs
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded local_cache.prep_jid
[INFO    ] Got return from ip-172-31-56-169.ec2.internal for job 20150819212253239143  
[DEBUG   ] Sending event - data = {'fun_args': [], 'jid': '20150819212253239143', 'return': ['Specified SLS apache in saltenv base is not available on the salt master or through a configured fileserver'], 'retcode': 1, 'success': True, 'cmd': '_return', '_stamp': '2015-08-19T21:22:53.520679', 'fun': 'state.highstate', 'id': 'ip-172-31-56-169.ec2.internal', 'out': 'highstate'}
```

As you can see there is nothing in there about python-git not working.  I did install `apt-get install python-git` before trying anything.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to specify the `fileserver_backend` in master configuration. This is by default set to `roots`.

**/etc/salt/master**

```
fileserver_backend:
  - roots
  - git

gitfs_remotes:
  - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/jenkins-formula.git
  - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/apache-formula.git
```